# installing ROS2 on a system which already has ROS1?

Tags: ros

I have ROS1 kinetic runing on Ubuntu 16.04. Now I want to install ROS2 Humble. May I also install ROs2 on the same system? if yes, how?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can install ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 16.04 would be if there is   Docker for your OS version.

ROS 2 Humble is targeted at Ubuntu 22.04 btw, which the Dockerfile will setup.  Try following the ROS 2 Humble Docker installation - It may just work.

(You can also take a look at my [install ROS 2 Humble Docker scripts](https://github.com/slowrunner/pi5desk/tree/main/configs/docker) - you will need to change the paths but the steps are all there.)

Yes you can have ROS and ROS 2 on the same system, and there is even a ros-bridge that you can run to have ROS 2 nodes see ROS topics.

Comment: after running sudo apt update, i have the following error:  

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1622248854
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1622248854
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 0):

ROS2 has also different distributions and prebuilt binaries for your Ubuntu version.
Of course it can coexist with ROS1 in your system, just remember to update your ~/.bashrc.
But you must be careful which version you install and how.

For example, the only official Ubuntu distro that supports both ROS2 (Foxy) and ROS1 (Noetic) is Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.

If you don't find a ROS2 distro that matches your ubuntu distro, I suggest you to pick the closest ROS2 distro to your system and [build it from source](https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/Installation/Linux-Development-Setup.html).